# Windows 7 link oddity

Tags: windows-7, command-line, links

The following happens on a command prompt in Windows 7.
The oddity is that it is possible to create a link but then it is not possible to change directory to the new link. Are you able to explain it?

```
C:\Luca\programs>mklink /D Screen_recorder_OBSstudio ..versioned/OBS-studio-0.15.2
Invalid switch - "OBS-studio-0.15.2".

C:\Luca\programs>mklink /D Screen_recorder_OBSstudio "..versioned/OBS-studio-0.15.2"
symbolic link created for Screen_recorder_OBSstudio <<===>> ..versioned/OBS-studio-0.15.2

C:\Luca\programs>cd Screen_recorder_OBSstudio
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 2):

#### It is possible to create a link but then it is not possible to change directory to the new link.

> Are you able to explain it?

Yes.

> mklink /D Screen_recorder_OBSstudio "..versioned/OBS-studio-0.15.2"

You have successfully created a link called `Screen_recorder_OBSstudio` to a target called `..versioned/OBS-studio-0.15.2`.

Unfortunately `..versioned/OBS-studio-0.15.2` is not a valid directory name, so when you try to `cd` to it you get an error.

I suspect you need to use one of the following target names (depending on where the target directory is actually located, relative to where the directory containing the new link is):

- `versioned\OBS-studio-0.15.2`
- `.\versioned\OBS-studio-0.15.2`
- `..\versioned\OBS-studio-0.15.2`

Notes:

- It is better to use `\` as a directory path element delimiter instead of `/`.

---

#### Can I create a link that point to a non-existent target?

Yes.

Apart from `mklink /h` (hardlink) the other `mklink` options all allow links to "point to a non-existent target":

> [image]

Source [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html).

This means you can create the link first and create the target later (at which point the link will start working).

**Example**:

```
F:\test>dir foo
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

File Not Found

F:\test>mklink /d alink foo
symbolic link created for alink <<===>> foo

F:\test>dir foo
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

File Not Found

F:\test>md foo

F:\test>dir foo
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\foo

01/08/2016  12:34    <DIR>          .
01/08/2016  12:34    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,772,975,259,648 bytes free
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) - Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Thanks for the hints.

The problem was typing

```
"..versioned/OBS-studio-0.15.2"
```

instead of

```
"..versioned\OBS-studio-0.15.2".
```

For the record, I have many other links to directories under

```
..versioned\
```

and they give no problem.
What was misleading was that mklink acknowledged without any problem the creation of the link, when using / instead of \

```
C:\Luca\programs>mklink /D Screen_recorder_OBSstudio "..versioned/OBS-studio-0.15.2"
symbolic link created for Screen_recorder_OBSstudio <<===>> ..versioned/OBS-studio-0.15.2
```

Comment: I'm happy it works. Please don't forget to [accept my answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).